# PC wont detect second monitor

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

Graphics Card: Asus Radeon 6950
OS: Windows 7

So basically, my graphics card has 2 DVI outputs (and another, I forget what it is).
The primary monitor is connected via DVI and runs at 1920x1080

The second monitor only I'm trying to use a DVI->VGA converter - and the max resolution on it is less than the res the primary runs on.

But in catalyst control centre, it wont detect the second monitor.
I have 2 to try (well one monitor + one TV)

So my question is Why!?

Untested theories of mine:
Card will not accept DVI + VGA connections running different resolutions (could I fix with a DVI->HDMI converter and run the TV at the same resolution?).

Graphics card broked.

Graphics card installation error (not drawing enough power?).

Answer (score 1):

I know for a fact that your first theory (Card will not accept DVI + VGA connections running different resolutions) is not true.  My other half has an AMD 6750 running a 1920*1080 monitor over DVI, and the other running a 1280*1024 through a DVI to VGA adaptor.

Have you tried the VGA monitor without the DVI monitor connected at the same time?  Do you get any output at all on the VGA monitor?  It may be that that the VGA monitor simply is not working.

Do you have any other DVI to VGA adaptors available?  Some can be unreliable and I have had a few that just didn't work.

To test whether the graphics card is working on that port simply swap which ports your monitors are connected on, the card should redetect the monitor(s) for you without a problem and your display should just reappear.

Comment: (if i can say this right) for a DVI port to output Analog for VGA it has to be available there, it is not created from the digital data. The Duel video cards, have analog avilable only on the one port, aparentally. http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CFAQFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.power-color.com%2FManual%2F090106%2FRadeon_HD_6900_Series_ENG.pdf&ei=ggGcTuiMJqbmiAK476irDQ&usg=AFQjCNF_m8ZHYARx1UTg6_BOzzUn6whvDw see chapter 4 page 11.  Difference between DVI-D and DVI-I ??  Other users saying the same thing found that the VGA indeed would work on the other port. as above